# add object data to existing firebase document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I’m having problems finding the the right approach to adding new data to a Firebase document (using JavaScript)

My document structure is as follows..

[image: Firebase document structure]

I want to be able to add a new child (as in kids) and a new class (as in school classes) objects to the children and classes arrays. I tried update, but that just overwrote existing data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [FieldValue.arrayUnion()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#static-array-union) to [add a new element to an array field](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) of a document.